# Gulp interface not hinted in intellisense

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have installed the `gulp` definition from the DefinitelyTyped repository, along with node.d.ts, but in Code I see no intellisense.

```
// gulpfile.ts
/// <reference path="./typings/gulp/gulp.d.ts" />
let gulp: Gulp = require("gulp"); // Cannot find name Gulp
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `/// <reference ...>`
2. Use import syntax: `import * as gulp from 'gulp';`

To be sure follow these steps:

1. Install gulp via npm
2. Install typings via npm
3. Add in package.json in scripts section: `"postinstall": "typings install --save"`
4. Add typings.json alongside package.json

   `{
     "globalDependencies": {
       "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts",
       "gulp": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/gulp/gulp.d.ts"
     }
   }`
5. run `npm install`

These steps should get you working gulp + typings for it.

Comment: Sorry `import * as gulp from 'gulp';` returns Cannot find module gulp, which I installed via `npm` nonetheless...

Comment: It should be something with you local environment. Please check the steps I have outlined in updated answer